# How to show files in browser with DataUrl format?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am receiving files (pdf, images, text, bmp, xlsx, docx, xls, doc) in DataUrl format.

How I can render these types of files in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the data

Image:

```html
<div>
  <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>

<div>
  <p>pdf</p>
  <object id="pdf" data="application/pdf;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO" type="application/pdf"></object>
</div>  

and so on
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried to do with object but it just shows blank window.